How to implement a 'Direct Messages' notification toggle in my iOS app's settings?
I struggle figuring out how to implement the Direct Messages notifications in my application. So my question is: how to make your app displaying the "Direct Messages" switch under its notification settings (in the "Always deliver immediately" section) and then, how to send this type of notification.
I feel like Alice in Wonderland because I see screenshots of this feature online, yet none of the apps on my phone (iOS 18.1) have this setting, and I can't find a single word in the documentation about how to implement it.
Example
I've read the apple documents and searched internet.

Add the communications notifications capability to your app https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/implementing-communication-notifications

@Paulw11 Oh man, thank you! No wonder I couldn't find it - the name “direct messages” is apparently not used anywhere.
